# Clustering- Plotting largest n clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm using HOPACH clustering- is there a way to visualize only the largest *n* clusters (Ex. Plot only the 3 largest)? Current code visualizes all clusters.

```
library(cluster)
library(hopach) 

distance =distancematrix(DNA[1:30],"cosangle")
hobpach.DNA =hopach(DNA[1:30],dmat=distance)

labels = c(hobpach.DNA$clustering$labels) 

table(labels, DNA$class)

#Plots all clusters

clusplot(DNA[1:30], hobpach.DNA$clustering$labels, main='Cluster Vis',
     color=TRUE, shade=TRUE,
     labels=2, lines=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like this directly in `clusplot`. But you can easily find out which clusters are largest and then only give these to the `clusplot` function.

```
# find the indicees of the largest clusters
biggest_indicees <- labels %in% names(sort(table(labels), decreasing = TRUE)[1:3])

# plot three largest clusters
clusplot(df[biggest_indicees, ], labels[biggest_indicees], main = 'Cluster Vis',
         color = TRUE, shade = TRUE, labels = 2, lines = 0)
```

Comment: I'm having a slight issue...                                                                                     Error in df[biggest_indicees, ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Did you define labels as you mention in the code above? There you have `labels = c(hobpach.DNA$clustering$labels) `.

Comment: Yes, exactly- I've searched this issue online yet no luck.

Comment: Try just printing out labels to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: I believe it is what I want.                                                                  'str(labels)                                                                                                              num [1:846] 32000 22000 10000 22000 31100 ...'

Comment: biggest_indicees result is exactly what I was looking for.